# java - Eclipse Helios SR 2 Package explorer error

Tags: eclipse, ide, package, explorer, helios

I need help. I was starting to work on a new project in Eclipse and so I decided to rid my package explorer space of any past projects within the IDE. I had 2 projects saved prior to opening the IDE: "new" and "project 1." I proceeded to delete project 1 successfully from the IDE permanently without any issues so I tried to delete "new." "new" was a project directory saved on my desktop and upon deletion within the IDE by right clicking, it deleted random files and folders on my desktop as well as other files I'm not aware of within a second, completely bypassing recycle bin-around 50GB of files. I tried to recover most of the files but they are fragmented and therefore damaged. Is this behaviour normal in Eclipse?

Comment: I think the second project was using some dependent files out side its project folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically in eclipse when you create a project, you create in a workspace. By default the project gets stored in the work space folder. However you can give a specific directory to save your project

The work space folder will usually have information regarding the projects. In eclipse we have 2 kind of delete. i.e.

1) Logical:- Project will get deleted from work space but there wont be any actual delete of files.

2) Physical:- Complete deletion of project.

I guess you would have opted the second one and the project would be corrupt. May be it had some dependent files outside which got deleted also.

usually when I want to remove the project , I go for soft delete. When I completely want to remove the project then I browse and delete the project folder itself.

You can find other related help regarding Eclipse in

http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp

Comment: Partha, thank you for your informative answer. I'm new to the eclipse IDE coming from C so I did not expect it would delete dependent files as well. I wanted to remove the project folder completely but not the dependent files (e.g, music mp3 files).

Comment: It happes :) It takes a bit time to get comfortable in eclipse :). Once comfortable you will love it